# If isomorphic image of ring $f(R)$ has unity does it mean the ring $R$ has unity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Apologies in advance if this has been asked before, I'm able to prove this but am doubtful if there's a counter example to disprove it.

If a homomorphic image of a ring $R'$ has unity  does not imply $R$ has unity

But I feel for an isomorphic image $R'$ of a ring $R$, $unity \in R'\implies unity \in R $ 
Couldn't find any proofs in a cursory search hence asking here. Thanks for your response.

[Edit for duplicate marking - It talks about an onto homomorphism but not an onto *and* one-to-one homomorphism?]

Comment: I am sorry, could you explain the title question? Does it say, that if $f:R\rightarrow S$ is a ring homomorphism with $R\cong f(R)$, and $f(R)$ has a unity, so does $R$? Of course, we have $R\cong f(R)$.

Comment: Yep that was the question.
Cool thanks